# sh: /usr/bin/ffmpeg: not found

Tags: php, audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to execute ffmpeg from PHP using shell_exec or exec but it fails. Why can this be? The command `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` works from the terminal, so I tried

```
<?php
$cmd = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg";
exec($cmd." 2>&1", $out, $ret);
if ($ret){
    echo "There was a problem!\n";
    print_r($out);
}else{
    echo "Everything went better than expected!\n";
}
?>
```

and I keep on getting

```
There was a problem! Array ( [0] => sh: /usr/bin/ffmpeg: not found )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Permission on the executable are

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root      106552 Jun 12 09:53 ffmpeg
```

Running `which /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` into $cmd returns an empty Array.

Comment: It works from the terminal on your computer, or from shell/ssh access on the server? Any safe_mode restrictions, an Apache chroot, or SELinux perhaps?

Comment: * and also permissions on the executable

Comment: Added permissions and it works on shell/ssh access on the server. php safe_mode is Off.

Comment: Also $cmd = "php" works.

Comment: Not sure how to test that? I am logged in as a user, but when the PHP call is made, I'm not sure?

Comment: Set $cmd to whoami and get the output.

Comment: It ends up being me (Rio) - I'm on a school network so it uses authentication that I have to sign in to.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` or `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` - you've used both paths in your question - so check you're on the right one.

Comment: What about symlinking to ffmpeg in the same directory as where your script is running from with $cmd = "./ffmpeg" or $cmd = "ffmpeg" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question might be simpler than expected.  You're checking in both `/usr/local/bin` *and* `/usr/bin`.  There are multiple solutions to this.

1. You can run `$ whereis ffmpeg` and see what you get.  Based on the results, change your `$cmd` variable.  If `whereis` returns nothing, then your system doesn't know where it is.  You can add it to your `$PATH` environment variable and try again.
2. You can try to run `$ find /usr -name "ffmpeg"` or something similar.  By ensuring that this program is installed, it will help you resolve this quicker.
3. If there is some sort of restriction denying apache the ability to access/use ffmpeg, you can always store it in a bin folder within your document root. (something like **/path/to/doc/root/bin/ffmpeg**) I have done this before so I know it works.

---

If you find that **ffmpeg** is actually located in `/usr/local/bin` then you should just try changing your `$cmd` to this:

```
$cmd = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg';
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up making a copy of ffmpeg and storing it in my own local folder. I think it was what you said with 3.

Comment: @Rio indeed.  Sometimes (depending on your server/hosting env) it's just much easier to do that.  It's the exact same reason I did it that way. I am glad you got this resolved though!  Question: Did you call it using a full absolute path or relative path?

Answer (score -2):

There was a problem!

```
Array (
  [0]  => FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  [1]  => built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
  [2]  => configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64
          --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth
          --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions
          -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC'
          --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac
          --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm
          --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb
          --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora
          --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads
         --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  [3]  => libavutil 50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  [4]  => libavcodec 52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  [5]  => libavformat 52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  [6]  => libavdevice 52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  [7]  => libavfilter 1.19. 0 / 1.19. 0
  [8]  => libswscale 0.11. 0 / 0.11. 0
  [9]  => libpostproc 51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  [10] => Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
  [11] => Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
  [12] => usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]...
          {[outfile options] outfile}...
  [13] =>
)
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a question? This is the place for answers. If you tried this solution and it did not work for you, you may open another question with a good description of your problem.